# Rails 5 apps connected to Docker + Puma (Nginx) + PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, puma

I've seen a few tutorials but cannot manage to set it up just as I'd like.

I have a number of Rails apps which I do not want to place inside a Docker container as it makes things such as running tasks or migrations a bit annoying. However, I'd like to connect these apps to Nginx (with Rails 5's default Puma server) and PostgreSQL containers with Docker. What is the correct way to set this up? Is this even possible? I'm thinking of something like the following:

```
app1     app2     app3
  \       |        /
   \      |       /
    \     |      /
     \    |     /
       --------
       |Docker|
       --------
  ======= ============
  |Nginx| |PostgreSQL|
  ======= ============
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can declare `nginx` and `postgres` services in `docker-compose.yml` that bind to ports of the host machine listening for connection the same way as though running directly on the host machine. You can then proxy connections to all 3 of the rails apps in your nginx configuration.

Comment: Yes how might I configure something like that?